# Need to extract all links from a CSV that contains several HTMLs -all links from each HTML

Tags: python, hyperlink, extract

I have a CSV containing a string of HTMLs.

I need to extract all links from each and every HTML in that CSV

Comment: Please provide more info. Make an example.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this will do what you want.

```
import csv 
import urllib2
import re

urls = csv.reader(open('C:\\your_path_here\\download_data.csv'))
for url in urls:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url[0])
    html = response.read()
    print re.findall('msApplication-PackageFamilyName',html)
```

##################

```
In the CSV file:
http://www.cnn.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.cbc.ca
```